# change branch master in vs code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

New to using github in VS Code and accidentally did  git  init on a high level folder when in fact i meant a low level sub folder. I've tried to do everything i can to un-assign this folder as it has over 5000 items in (.js libraries etc!) but can't seem to google the right solution. If i check git status in the terminal window i get

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        FreeCodeCamp/
        folder1/
        Test web/
        Web cheat sheet.html
        index.html
        my_profile_pic-min.jpg
        my_profile_pic.jpg
        folder2/
        bio/
        blog/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
PS D:\Web Design>
```

Not really sure how to remove/change the master folder to the freecodecamp sub folder.

All help welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Go into the actual folder you want to version control with git and do git init in there. You can use command line arguments like git checkout to change the branch if needed. (Doing git init will create new repository for you). Then you are safe to delete the other repository you initialised accidentally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had initialized the folder i wanted but VS Code wasn't letting me do anything as the master with the un-tracked files seemed to be blocking everything. My solution ended up being to delete the .git folder from via the command line from the root folder, essentially freeing up the master.

Comment: Have a look at this page, might have the info you looking for. https://www.xenovation.com/blog/source-control-management/git/how-to-change-remote-git-repository

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the `.git` directory in the high level directory to stop git tracking there, and then do `git init` again in the appropriate sub-directory to initialize that as a git repository.